# CURL is not returning any data?

Tags: php, api, curl

I am using curl to get data from API, that is returning me different guid every time. i am using the below code:

```
$curl_handle=curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL,'https://aapiconvention2016.sched.org/api/auth/login?api_key=f8bf836da29b0831ff1f03fce3c64462&username=*****&password=****');
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 2);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'API HIT');
$query = curl_exec($curl_handle);
curl_close($curl_handle);
echo $query
```

before it was returning 500 internal error. i fixed it by using above code. but now i am not getting any error or output.

i am not getting why it is not working, please help me

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please set  ssl verification false by add this line

```
curl_setopt($curl_handle,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
```

and then your code will be like this :

```
$curl_handle=curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_URL,'https://aapiconvention2016.sched.org/api/auth/login?api_key=f8bf836da29b0831ff1f03fce3c64462&username=*****&password=****');
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 2);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'API HIT');
curl_setopt($curl_handle,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
$query = curl_exec($curl_handle);
curl_close($curl_handle);
echo $query;
```

Comment: I tried with this url https://aapiconvention2016.sched.org/api/auth/login bcz , i have not any credentials on this website, and it's return me "ERR: Authorization failed.ERR: Access denied"

Comment: i have added creds into your answer.. please chech

Comment: now it's returning 719fed9278a2806651dbf0bf5b02733627f7992b

Comment: you have hit the url directly or used the code, i mean curl?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112228/discussion-between-manmohan-and-ram-singh).

Answer (score 1):

You can get the last error code using `curl_errno` and the last error string using `curl_error`. These gave me a timeout error.

Therefore you can get an answer by increasing the default curl timeout to e.g. 10 seconds and the overall function timeout to e.g. 15 seconds:

```
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
curl_setopt($curl_handle, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 15);
```